# Getting a wrong object through behavior subject

Tags: angular, rxjs

I don't know whether this is the default behavior how the data emitted using behavior subject works. In this plunker demo, http://plnkr.co/edit/kFdD1Pqn5j3ELUc89ztm?p=preview the first tab component and the second tab component subscribes to the same behavior subject.

The first tab is getting the data correctly which is emitted by the subject, but the second tab component is loaded dynamically, and it also subscribes to the same subject, but this is receiving wrong data.

This is how I am subscribing the subject in first tab component:

```
      this.srvc.Data.subscribe(data=> {
    let FormData=data;
    this.CreateForm(FormData);
  });
```

This is how I created a form in first tab

```
CreateForm(data){
if(data.LName == null){
data.LName='Ram'
}
  this.myForm = this.localfb.group({  
  'First':  [data.fname, Validators.required]  ,
  'Second':[data.LName]
});  
}
```

This is how I subscribed in second tab component.

```
      this.subscription = this.srvc.Data.subscribe(data=> {
    console.log('Sample1',data);
  });
```

The data emitted by the subject is an object and has only one property which is received correctly in first tab component but not in second tab. Is this the default behavior how this works?

Comment: Please review guidelines for debugging questions : http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. In particular : `
Describe the problem. "It doesn't work" is not a problem statement. Tell us what the expected behavior should be.`

Comment: 1)Are you creating two instances of the srvc class? or using one for both?
2)Did you verify that it is correct in one place and wrong in the other? by logging the first one's subscription